# Getting error during the time of inserting the query on database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am Facing the error at the time of insert the query.

```
Error is "db.collection.insert is not a function"
```

My database schema is like this

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Schema
var ABCSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        sequenceid: {
            type: Number
        },
        A: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
        B: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
        C: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
        D: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        }
});

var ABC = module.exports = mongoose.model('ABC', ABCSchema);
```

Now I want to enter the data which looks like this.
It's just a sample by which you people can understand that how I can Store the value.

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a2e2eb9104cce1b58385620"),
 "sequenceid": 1,
 "A" : [ 
        {
            "apple" : "red",
            "count" : 24
        }
    ],
 "B" : [],
 "C" : [],
 "D" : [],
  "__v" : 0
}
```

Now what I am trying to code is like this

```
ABC.insert({'sequenceid': 1, 'A': {'apple': 'red', 'count': 24}}, function(error, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: you may trying to code like ABC.insert, not db.collection.insert

Comment: I think now error also change `Error is "db.collection.insert is not a function"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Manjeet Thakur pointed out what you are trying to insert at `"A"` is and object and not an Array

Change it to array

```
{
  "A": [{
    "apple": "red",
    "count": 24
  }],
  "sequenceid": 1
}
```

Also you need to instantiate your model and save it

```
var abc = new ABC({'sequenceid': 1, 'A': [{'apple': 'red', 'count': 24}]});
abc.save()

//or

ABC.create({'sequenceid': 1, 'A': [{'apple': 'red', 'count': 24}]}, function (err, small) {
  //if (err) return throw err;
  // saved!
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    'use strict';
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    //Schema
    var ABCSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            sequenceid: {
                type: Number
            },
            A: {
                type: Array,
                default: []
            },
            B: {
                type: Array,
                default: []
            },
            C: {
                type: Array,
                default: []
            },
            D: {
                type: Array,
                default: []
            }
    });

    var ABC = module.exports = mongoose.model('ABC', ABCSchema);

   // here now collection is ABC (name of collection)
    ABC.insert({'sequenceid': 1, 'A': [{'apple': 'red', 'count': 24}] }, function(error, data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: I am just Describing. Actually I did Like this. ABC.insert()

Comment: so what issue in this you see?

Comment: Anyone can just copy/paste a code, can you please elaborate.